# How to create a plugin model using struts 2,JPA

Tags: struts2, jpa-2.0

Greetings for the day!!

I am working on struts 2 with JPA 2(Eclipse link).upto now we implemented all the modules in a single project.But one new module was come in to picture.we want to develop this as separate plug in which will be used when it is added in project.Otherwise it should not effect the existing project.
To make this,we have facing some challenges like

1. The extra classes are added in Persistence to develop the module.we are not aware about making the persistence in to two parts.One for existing project and other one is plug ins persistence
2. Other one is struts.xml file.

Please provide me some suggestions regarding this 
Thanking you for spending your precious time for resolving this issue

Comment: You could add other module as a jar, plugin extends the framework not your application.

Comment: You can include other configuration files in `struts.xml`.

Comment: Thanking you for sharing your suggestions with me.According to your conversation,In our module,model classes,Action classes,DAO's,JSP,js,lib files are present.Now we will bundle all of them as single jar.and place that respective jar in lib file.My doubt is ,how the respective model classes will be configured in persistance,how the actions are configured in struts.xml,and how we can access the jsp and js files.Please provide me brief example.which helps me a lot